# How to set page content margins for Kindle?

Tags: css, html, kindle

I'm converting html page for Kindle. The page have multiple CSS files. Kindle Guide recommends set left and right margins to 0 for normal body text to keep content from falling off the edge of the screen or overlapping other content, and body text must not have a forced alignment. The CSS already have margins to zero, and no text-align is specified. Problem is that converted article text is too close to the edges of the screen, for some reason Kindle not set default margins between content and the edges of the screen.

I tried set padding 1.2 - 1.3em for right and left side, it do set some spacing, but in the middle of ebook I see it starts overlapping on the right edge of the pages, so the edges of pictures and text are clipped.
How to modify CSS to set proper margins between right and left border of content and screen edges? I use KindleGen for converting.

Here is page [sample](http://bit.ly/18hCJk3).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, with a kindle ebook it really depends on which format you want to convert to, the older (for Kindle Keyboard models) or the new KF8? And why don't you remove all the styling (applying a CSS reset) before the conversion?

I'd recommend to read [this (and several other) thread](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=216406) on Mobileread.